# Eclipse allows Repository cloning without authentication

Tags: eclipse, authentication, uri, clone, gerrit

Using Eclipse Kepler SR1, EGit 3.2.0, Mylyn 3.9, the whole nine yards....

When I enter the Clone URI settings from either "File >> Import >> Git >> Projects from GIT >> Clone URI" or "Clone a GIT repository and add the clone to this view" button, and I enter the relevant settings, such as "ssh://username@mylocalhost:29418/projectname", I'm obligated to provide Authentication (username and password).

I've noticed the following errors:

(a) Eclipse allows access to the server without any password (tried this with multiple users)

(b) With my username, there is no obligation to type the username with a capital initial letter ["Alex" and "alex" both work fine], but with another user there is a mismatch ["Brian" required; "brian" fails].

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Furthermore, can I change the settings for (a) so that it ALWAYS requires a password i.e. it does not authenticate without a password?

PS: Necessary to mention that all users (Alex and/or Brian) are Administrators and Functional Users with similar privileges and rights.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you have some password-daemon running in the background, eclipse uses automatically? I don't know where you're cloning from, but as far as I know, cloning from github via https doesn't need auth.

Comment: The server is a Gerrit-GIT Server, where log-in can only occur with a username + password (through a web browser). Technically, anyone who has access to the URI can access the elements of the project. This has to be restricted. 

Also, I'm using ssh, not http(s).

Comment: Sure. Are you sure your gerrit-git server has auth enabled when accessing via git? I don't know how gerrit works, but this could be the security hole. Also, you should tag you question with `gerrit` if this is/appears to be gerrit related!

Comment: Are you sure your gerrit-git server has auth enabled when accessing via git? >> you mean from eclipse (which by default gives you the option to enter a username and password), or you mean directly from a web browser? From / in the web browser authentication a user HAS to log in with credentials to view branches, check settings, enter keys, change access rights et al.

Comment: Are you using ssh keys rather than passwords?

Comment: Just username and passwords, not ssh keys for authentication....

Comment: UPDATE: 

Stash provides a simple way for user accounts and other systems to connect to repositories for Git operations, using SSH keys.

You can add a personal key to a Stash user account to allow a developer to easily authenticate when performing read-write operations from his or her local machine. 

You can add an access key to a Stash project or repository to allow other systems, such as build servers - like Atlassian's Bamboo - to authenticate "read-only operations (pull and clone)", without the need to store user credentials. 

Am I answering myself....??